# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string' Couldn't fix this

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, spyder

Trying to work with BeautifulSoup but I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

The problem is with this line

```
_a = _dev.find('a')
```

Here is my code:

```
for _dev in devs:
_d = _dev.find('div')
authors.append(_d.text.strip())

_a = _dev.find('a')
if not _a.string is None:
    names.append(_a.text.strip())
    if 'href' in _a.attrs.keys():
        urls.append(_a.get('href'))
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely with this line `if not _a.string is None:`.

If `_dev.find('a')` does not find what you're looking for it returns `None`. Since you assigned the value to `_a`, that means you are calling `None.string` on that line, which will definitely raise an error.

Change that line to this:

```
if _a and not _a.string is None:
```

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. Kindly accept it as your answer if it answers your question.